# finding sublist in lists with map/select in mathematica

Tags: list, wolfram-mathematica

I have, in Wolfram Mathematica 8.0, a nested list like

`nList = {{a,b},{f,g},{n,o}}`

and a normal list like

`lList = {a,b,c,k,m,n,o,z}`

and i want to check if all the sublists in nList are in lList (in the example a,b and n,o are there but not f,g)

I've done it using `For[,,,]` and using index... can someone enlighten me in using functions like Map/Thread/Select to do it in one pass.

Edit: If `nList` contains `a,b`, `lList` must contain `a,b` and not `a,c,b` or `b,a` or `b,c,a`

Comment: Edit: If nList contains a,b lList must contain a,b and not a,c,b or b,a or b,c,a ...

Comment: Are the sublists always the same length as each other?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you don't care about element ordering, here is one way:

```
In[20]:= Complement[Flatten[nList],lList] ==={}

Out[20]= False
```

**EDIT**

If the order matters, then here is one way:

```
In[29]:= And@@(MatchQ[lList,{___,PatternSequence[##],___}]&@@@nList)

Out[29]= False
```

For large number of sub-lists, this may be faster:

```
In[34]:= 
Union[ReplaceList[lList,
       {___,x:Alternatives@@(PatternSequence@@@nList),___}:>{x}]]===Union[nList]

Out[34]= False
```

This works as follows: [ReplaceList](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ReplaceList.html) is a very nice but often ignored command which returns a list of all possible expressions which could be obtained with the pattern-matcher trying to apply the rules in  all possible ways to an expression. This is in contrast with the way the pattern-matcher usually works, where it stops upon the first successful match. The [PatternSequence](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PatternSequence.html)  is a relatively new addition to the Mathematica pattern language, which allows us to give an identity to a given sequence of expression, treating it as a pattern. This allowed us to construct the alternative pattern, so the resulting pattern is saying: the sequence of any sublist in any place in the main list is collected and put back to list braces, forming back the sublist. We get as many newly formed sublists as there are sequences of the original sublists in the larger list. If all sublists are present, then `Union` on the resulting list should be the same as `Union` of the original sublist list.

Here are the benchmarks (I took a list of integers, and overlapping sublists generated by `Partition`):

```
In[39]:= tst = Range[1000];

In[41]:= sub = Partition[tst, 2, 1];

In[43]:= 
And @@ (MatchQ[tst, {___, PatternSequence[##], ___}] & @@@ sub) // Timing

Out[43]= {3.094, True}

In[45]:= 
Union[ReplaceList[tst, {___,x : Alternatives @@ (PatternSequence @@@ sub), ___} 
     :> {x}]] ===  Union[sub] // Timing

Out[45]= {0.11, True}
```

Conceptually, the reason why the second method is faster is that it does its work in the single run through the list (performed internally by `ReplaceList`), while the first solution explicitly iterates through the big list for each sub-list.

**EDIT 2 - Performance**

If performance is *really* an issue, then the following code is yet much faster:

```
And @@ (With[{part = Partition[lList, Length[#[[1]]], 1]},
 Complement[#, part] === {}] & /@SplitBy[SortBy[nList, Length], Length])
```

For example, on our benchmarks:

```
In[54]:= And@@(With[{part = Partition[tst,Length[#[[1]]],1]},
       Complement[#,part]==={}]&/@SplitBy[SortBy[sub,Length],Length])//Timing

Out[54]= {0.,True}
```

**EDIT 3**

Per suggestion of @Mr.Wizard, the following performance improvement can be made:

```
Scan[
 If[With[{part = Partition[lList, Length[#[[1]]], 1]},
   Complement[#, part] =!= {}], Return[False]] &,
 SplitBy[SortBy[nList, Length], Length]
] === Null
```

Here, the as soon as we get a negative answer from sub-lists of a given length, sublists of other lengths will not be checked, since we already know that the answer is negative (`False`). If `Scan` completes without `Return`, it will return `Null`, which will mean that `lList` contains all of the sublists in `nList`.

Comment: that means that if nList contains a,b or b,a and lList contains both a and b in whatever order it'll always work?
Then i need something more specific if nList contains a,b lList must contain a,b and not a,c,b or b,a or b,c,a ...

Comment: Yes. But if you want to check that `lList` literally contains the sequence `a,b` in that order, and with no elements in between, like in `{c,d,a,b,e}`, then you need some more work. Is that the case?

Comment: Please see my edit, there is a solution there that takes order into account

Comment: Nice, altough i don't understand quite well the one for large numbers of sublists ... 

You use ReplaceList on the main list with all the possible expression derived from nList?

Comment: Oh drat, you beat me again. ;-p

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Not for long, I am sure :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Indeed, yours is about 2-3 times faster, but mine is more general, since it does not impose any conditions - lists can be of different lengths, duplicate etc. A usual tradeoff - generality vs. speed.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - no, mine will work also for sublists of different lengths (I hope)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I first split all sublists into sublists of sublists, according to their lengths (this is why I sort). Then, I test separately for a given sublength list (by Mapping `With[...]`), and finally I combine results together.

Comment: By the way, if you want to be really fast, and handle sublists of different lengths, shouldn't you check `True` between length passes, rather than after all are done?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I just thought about it - but this time you were faster :). Can easily implement with `Scan`. I will edit my post.

Comment: Thank you guys for the different solutions and explanations. You were both great :)

Comment: Congratulations on the Mortarboard, Leonid!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks! Although I'd prefer having less bronze badges, since I like high silver/bronze number of badges ratio :)

Comment: Don't be too picky!  Of course I suppose that helps you write those fine answers of yours...

Answer (score 6):

You could use pattern matching to do this job:

```
In[69]:= nList = {{a, b}, {f, g}, {n, o}};
lList = {a, b, c, k, m, n, o, z};
```

The `@@@` is an alias for `Apply` at level `{1}`. The level 1 of `nList` contains your pairs, and applying replaces the head `List` in them with the function to the right of `@@@`.

```
In[71]:= MatchQ[lList, {___, ##, ___}] & @@@ nList

Out[71]= {True, False, True}
```